# Handle post and get method in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, methods, error-handling, http-post

let's say we make a route

```
Routes::post('article/save_comment','articleController@save_comment');
```

Then we call this route by typing URL in browser with post nothing, and of course, it will be error and says 'The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST'
cz if we call this URL directly Laravel knowing this as get method(correct me if I'm wrong)

and the question is how to handle this error?
thanks

Comment: you want a route that can be used as post and get as well??

Answer (score 2):

You can try this in the Exception handler [#RenderMethod](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/errors#render-method)

```
if ($exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
    return response()->view('your-custom-error-view', []);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that anymore to handle the error. add 404.blade.php in your resources/views/errors folder and Laravel will handle 404 errors for you. or you can use match route method instead of `get`

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'],article/save_comment','articleController@save_comment');
```